# Emitting object or value in vue.js component child to parent communication

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I would like to know which is better way to emit data to parent in vue component. From parent to child I pass `prop` object but from child to parent with `$emit`. Should I pass object or value? e.g.: `{ product }` or `product.id` and also I have to reuse some data in the `{ product }` like `product.price` on event listener. What should I use? Emit an object or just value then loop and condition in listener function?

Comment: I'd suggest you to show some relevant code and describe expected results. "which is better way" is not a clear question, although somebody knowing the architecture well may suggest something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a two way sync here:

```
@product.sync="product"
```

In the child:

```
this.$emit('update:product', product)
```

Whenever you make a change to the property of the product.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work in case of Pass by reference. I mean it works but Vue is screaming don't mutate props directly...

Where movie is an object and genres is an array. Child components props and event

props: {
    genres: {
      type: Array,
      default () {
        return []
      }
    }
  }

...

this.$emit('changeGenreList', this.genres)

I had to make the local copy of this array with slice() and then I was emitting this copy.